# Calculate proportions for multiple variables according to factor level across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have survey data with several demographic variables and question variables that have been coded as binary data.

Demo variables look like this:

```
urban     labor_force            
<fct>     <fct>            
rural     in labor force            
urban     in labor force         
rural     not in labor force
```

Question variables look like this:

```
Q65_armedforces     Q69_police   Q70_courts
<int>               <int>        <int>
1                   1            1
1                   0            1
0                   0            0
```

The data set as a whole is structured like this:

```
urban     labor_force      Q65_armedforces     Q69_police   Q70_courts
<fct>     <fct>                <int>               <int>        <int>
rural    in labor force          1                   1            1 
urban    in labor force          1                   0            1
rural    not in labor force      0                   0            0
```

What I would like to achieve is a table that I can write to csv that has the proportion of 1s for each factor level in the demographic variables, for all of the question variables. So the final product would look like this (updated with actual numbers from dataset):

```
                    urban   rural   in labor force    not in labor force   
Q65_armed forces    0.85    0.88    0.86              0.86             
Q69_police          0.84    0.84    0.83              0.85                 
Q70_courts          0.74    0.76    0.75              0.75
```

Numbers derived from

```
wvs_final %>% group_by(urban) %>% summarize(mean(Q65_armedforces, na.rm=TRUE))
wvs_final %>% group_by(urban) %>% summarize(mean(Q69_police, na.rm=TRUE))
wvs_final %>% group_by(urban) %>% summarize(mean(Q70_courts, na.rm=TRUE))

wvs_final %>% group_by(labor_force) %>% summarize(mean(Q65_armedforces, na.rm=TRUE))
wvs_final %>% group_by(labor_force) %>% summarize(mean(Q69_police, na.rm=TRUE))
wvs_final %>% group_by(labor_force) %>% summarize(mean(Q70_courts, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I have about 50 question variables so I don't want to try and use group_by to get each of these individually, but am stuck on how I would go about automating this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: thank you for the response. I updated my post to be hopefully be clearer about what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and for each column calculate `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = urban:labor_force) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(across(Q65_armedforces:Q70_courts, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you, that gets me close to what I'm looking for--but how do I go to a format where the factor levels (urban, rural, in labor force, not in labor force) become the columns, and the questions (Q65_armedforces, Q69_police, Q70_courts) become the rows? I tried pivot_wider but got " Error: Column 1 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair. "

Comment: Add `%>% pivot_longer(cols = -value, values_to = 'val') %>% pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = val)` to the above answer.